# How to add multiselect stores in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, store-view, stores, multiselect-attribute

I'm working on a groupon like website and there is a frontend merchant dashboard to insert deals.
I need to show, in the frontend dashboard,  this multiselect from the backend. It just uses store views

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Magento `Adminhtml` module already has a model that can return an array with dropdown values as used in the `System > Configuration` section.

Check the `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Store` class.

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true)
```

Should provide you with what you need